# Check if Row's child is initialized

Tags: dart, flutter

In my flutter application I have multiple occurrences of the following code:

```
<Widget>[
  _isForecastLoaded
    ? new Center(
      child: new ForecastView(forecastDayDTOs: _forecast.forecast)
    )
    : new Center(),
...
]
```

which is basically a null checks. Without it I would have an exception saying that Row cannot have a null child. 
I think this is wrong, but not sure what is Dart/Flutter way of dealing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new ForecastView(forecastDayDTOs: _forecast.forecast)`  <- if this returns null, the `new Center(child: null)` will still works. So you don't have to check for null, just wrap your nullable widget inside `Center`

```
<Widget>[
   new Center(
      child: new ForecastView(forecastDayDTOs: _forecast.forecast) 
    )

...
]
```